# Android Studio - can't run project - Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio (been using eclipse until now). I started a new project. SDK version 4.0 (also tried different versions). Main Activity blank.

After the project initializes I see in the "Gradle Build" window the following errors:

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And of course I can't run the project. Nothing special here. Everything "out of the box".

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you check the `SDK Manager`? There are possible chances of broken files or the appropriate SDK is not installed

Comment: @KevinChris is there something specific I should be looking for to install?

Comment: Open the SDK Manager and check for broken files, If not in `Extras` make sure you have installed everything and post the `build.gradle`

Comment: Hi @developer82 If my solution worked, please don't forget to vote my answer up as well. Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compile SDK version must be like the support library's installed version.

I am assuming that you are using version 23 of the support library, since you have the latest Android Studio installed. So you need to compile your project with version 23 of the Android SDK too.

Open your SDK Manager and install the latest API so far which is API 23. Also update your Android Support Library and Android Support Repository in case there are updates to them, then create a new project and set target version to API 23.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: I'm really new to Android Studio and kind of lost here. Where do I check this? I just installed and started a new test project with all the defaults - why would this not just install, setup and work out of the box?

Comment: Now I'm getting: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: Your problem is fixed now. This is a different error when running the app and not related to the question. However, I'll help you too. Refer to that link and follow the instructions: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installing-the-intel-atom-x86-system-image-for-android-emulator-add-on-from-the-android-sdk-manager If that error still persists, then your computer specs might be low, try to install GenyMotion instead. Search for it on google.

Comment: If my solution fixed the other two errors, please don't forget to mark my answer as correct and vote it up. And if you need more help, tell me. Thanks. :)