# Build folder showing errors n

Tags: android, build

When i go to clean project I am left with 3 errors and I am not sure what to do, code below. Please could someone help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From:       
file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-   
 android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-
 release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-   
v23/styles_base_text.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"/>
<!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/themes_base.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat"/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
<style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

    <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
</style>
<style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

    <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
</style>
<!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio - can't run project - Error retrieving parent for item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158183/android-studio-cant-run-project-error-retrieving-parent-for-item)

Answer (score 0):

Check out your build.gradle file and make the changes as below,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.inzi.app"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Check for the compileSdkVersion (should be 23), buildTiilVersion (should be 23) and also the dependencies ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0')...

Let me know if it works...

And mark it as an answer so that it would be useful to others...